# Git rebase master on a new branch is giving merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, git-rebase

Okay, So here it is.

I got a lot of merge conflicts when I try to rebase it on my current feature branch. Master was ahead by like a hundred commits, so it was bound to happen.

So, What I though was to update origin master from upstream master, switch to origin master, and create a new branch called test.

And, when I try to run `git rebase master` after `git checkout -b test`, I get merge conflicts, which shouldn't happen.

Am I missing something very basic of how rebase works or what? because I think a git rebase master is kind of redundant after just creating a new branch from master..

Comment: If you are on branch master, and you do `git checkout -b test` the branche should be exactly the same. You can verify visually with something like `gitk` or run `git merge-base master test` to see where the branches divert.

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  If you branched off of an updated master branch, then the tips of test and master would be at the same commit so no rebasing would take place.  How did you update your master branch?

Comment: @Makoto, I used `git checkout master` followed by `git pull --rebase upstream/master`

Comment: @IgalS. ,  When I run `git merge-base master test` , I get a hash value, which I'm assuming is the last commit? Edit: No it is not the last commit id.

Comment: `git merge-base` gives you the common ancestor for the 2 branches. If it is not the last commit id then something in the branching you did is wrong. I suggest re-doing the steps. or again - use gitk to see the differences between branches in a visual way.

Comment: @IgalS. , Yup turns out, I did messed it up somewhere. So, I just hard reset it using `git reset --hard origin master` and I created a new branch from it. Now the rebase it working as it should, saying that everything is up to fate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up somewhere in the process of branching. I did the following to resolve the issue.

Since, all my changes that matter are already pushed to origin, I did a

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

which set me back to origin master, and now when I do create a new branch, I am not getting that error.